# Java Swing draw image after paintComponent called

Tags: java, swing

I am a little confused about how extending JPanel to make a canvas style object works in Swing, what would I do if I wanted to create a new image or text after I've made the new object? Since I assume that's when the paintComponent is called.

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=gJZvVOPTLLT_sAS3tILADQ&ved=0CBQQFjAA&sig2=kL4owINmtAOLLmtO8tRCFQ&usg=AFQjCNHkv5ISFDgkyC7FVWGorMLf92vUUQ

Comment: I've already looked at that, doesn't explain how to make something after paintComponent has run

Comment: Call `repaint()` after changes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the excellent advice from [ControlAltDel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1291492/controlaltdel) (see [step 3 of the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for information on how to programatically repaint) and [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson), this could be useful as a very simple example to help you get started:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing canvas");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 640, 480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final CanvasPanel canvasPanel = new CanvasPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvasPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        final List<String> words = Arrays.asList("one", "ein", "une", "uno", "jeden", "een");
        for (final String word : words) {
            canvasPanel.addWord(word);
            // Dirty way to simulate some heavy translation work...
            Thread.sleep(246);
        }
    }
}

class CanvasPanel extends JPanel {
    private final List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addWord(final String word) {
        words.add(word);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < words.size(); wordIndex++)
            graphics.drawString(words.get(wordIndex), 42, 64 + 28 * wordIndex);
    }
}
```

In this example, the canvas panel calls the repaint method on itself, but it can also be called from the outside. Good luck with your project!

Comment: So is paintComponent run repeatedly? As opposed to just once? Or whenever repaint is called?

Comment: Yes, it's called repeatedly, whenever the system determines it is necessary (for example when the panel is exposed after being hidden by another window) or when your program calls repaint. See the [Summary of the Custom Painting tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/summary.html) for a nice overview.

Comment: Oh I see, I understand now, thank you, this is where I was confused :)